# Swift D-Day UIPickerDate

Tags: swift, datepicker

I have a

```
@IBOutlet weak var EndDatePicker: UIDatePicker?
```

what I want to is, If a string called `date` is nil, set the datePicker to Today, the "D-Day":

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    if(task?.date != nil){
        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(task!.date!)
        EndDatePicker!.date = date!
    }else{
        //EndDatePicker!.date = D-Day?
    }
```

Thank you for your help, I don't find on internet the way to do this on swift.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
let text = dateString
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Swift 1.2 you can perform two optional binding checks in the same line.
The first check is if `date` is nil, the second if the `dateformatter` could create a valid date

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

if let dateString = task?.date, date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString) {
  EndDatePicker.date = date
}
else {
  EndDatePicker.date = NSDate()
}
```